# Can I delete an element of SetHash and use its value in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I would like to delete any element of a `SetHash`, so that its value be returned:

```perl6
my SetHash $a;
$a<m n k> = 1..*;
my $elem = $a.mymethod;
say $elem; # n
say $a; # SetHash(m k)
```

I can do it in two steps as follows. Is there a better way?

```perl6
my $elem = $a.pick;
$a{$elem}--;
```

And by the way, is there a more idiomatic way of adding several elements to a `SetHash`?

Is the following any better?

```perl6
my SetHash $a;
$a{$_}++ for <m n k>;
```

or

```perl6
my SetHash $a;
$a<m n k> X= True;
```

Comment: You can also add multiple elements using the hyper operator: `$a<a b c>»++`

Comment: Thanks, I found it. Probably a dot is missing in your variant.

Comment: You don't need dots for operators. Note that hypers notionally / semantically process *in parallel* so only use them with operations such that execution order and side-effects work when executed in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to remove any random element from the set and return the value you got, I'd recommend using the `grab` method on Setty things (only works properly on mutable sets like `SetHash`): https://docs.perl6.org/type/SetHash#(Setty)_method_grab

Depending on what exact return value you need, maybe grabpairs is better.

Comment: Oh, at last! That's exactly what I wanted, I strangely missed it in the docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**UPD** I'm leaving this answer up for now rather than deleting it, but see [timotimo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619506/1077672).

> I would like to delete an element of a SetHash, so that its value be returned

Use the `:delete` adverb.

Per [the Subscript doc page](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#:delete), 
the `:delete` adverb will delete the element(s) from the collection or, if supported by the collection, create a hole at the given index(es), in addition to returning their value(s):

```
my %associative = << :a :b :c >> ;
my $deleted = %associative<< a c >> :delete ;
say $deleted ;     # (True True)
say %associative ; # {b => True}
```

**UPD** Integrating @piojo's and @EugeneBarsky's comments and answers:

```
my %associative = << :a :b :c >> ;
my $deleted = .{.keys.pick } :delete :k with %associative ;
say $deleted ;     # b 
say %associative ; # {a => True, c => True}
```

> is there a more idiomatic way of adding several elements to a SetHash?

Plain assignment with a list on the right hand side works, e.g.

```
$a<m n k> = True, True, True;
$a<m n k> = True xx *;
$a<m n k> = True ... *;
```

I've used and seen others using both the formulations in your examples too.

Comment: Probably my question isn't clear enough. The problem is I don't know beforehand which element I want to delete, and I want to have its value (e.g. `'c'`), not `True`. So, I want to do something like `pop`.

Comment: `:delete` is like a general `pop`. I'm not sure what you're thinking there's a problem. For example, the element(s) can be chosen dynamically, e.g. `%myhash<<@elems>>:delete`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky You mean you want to delete a list of elements without knowing whether they exist, and afterwards have your return value say which ones were formerly part of the set?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your comments correctly, you want to delete an element from a hash without knowing whether it exists, and get the element as a return value if it does exist. This can be done by combining the `:delete` and `:k` adverbs.

```
my %set := SetHash.new: ('a'..'g');
my @removed = %set<a e i o u>:delete :k;
say @removed; # output: [a e]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot reading the answers! What I really wanted was to get *any* element of the `SetHash` as a return value and delete it from the `SetHash`. :) Like `pop`ping a random element (since there is no order in a `Set`).

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Oh, I finally understand what you meant. You can't do that in a single operation, because it's not such a common thing. There aren't many algorithms which require removing a random element from a set. In the cases where I've had to remove elements from a set, I found an array to be a better data structure because it allows one-time or progressive randomization. Nonetheless, that is a valid need, but it's not in the same league as `Array.pop`.

Comment: Thanks! So, I'll use my method with pick. I feel that my question was very poorly formulated, but nevertheless I learned a lot from the answers.

Comment: I've combined the answers, and seems managed to do what I wanted. Made an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594914/7730888) myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to deleting the element and returning it, is to augment the `SetHash` class with a custom method:

```
use v6;
use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class SetHash {
    method delete-elem(Any $elem) {
        self.DELETE-KEY( $elem );
        return $elem;
    }
}

my SetHash $a = <m n k>.SetHash;
$a<a b c>»++;  # add some more elements to the SetHash...

my $elem = $a.delete-elem( $a.pick );
say "Deleted: $elem";
say $a;
```

**Output**:

```
Deleted: m
SetHash(a b c k n)
```

Comment: Hi Håkon. I'm not seeing how your solution achieves something that isn't achieved by the built in `:delete` adverb (per my answer). Eugene seems to be saying I'm missing something but of course I'm not seeing what I'm not seeing... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of the answers, it seems I've managed to do what I wanted:

```perl6
my SetHash $s;
$s = <a b c d e f>.SetHash;
my $deleted = $s{ $s.pick } :delete :k;
say $deleted; # f
say $s; # SetHash(a b c d e)
```